# Iterating through a collection

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I am trying to create hasnext() has next() methods for a iterator so that the output of a collection will be:

```
"printing","elements","in","order","from","collection"
```

input:

```
[A] - ["printing", "elements", "in"]

[B] - ["order"]

[C] - ["from", "collection"]
```

At the moment I have my methods looking like:

```
    public MyIterator(Collection<Collection<Object>> myColl) {
    _myColl = myColl;
}


public boolean hasNext() {

    if(myColl.next != null)
    {
        return true
    }

    return !queue.isEmpty();
}


    public Object next() throws java.util.NoSuchElementException {

    //Dont really know what to put in here....


}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is declare a counter and increment when you are accessing the has next. In the logic if i will express, then that will be like this.

```
private int counter = 0;

public boolean hasNext(){
    counter = counter < collection.size()? counter + 1: counter;// increment
    return counter < collection.size();// check and give the appropriate boolean value
}

public T next(){
    return collection.get(counter);// to get the counter number of element
}
```

where **counter** is the private variable in the class and **T** is the generic type on which type of object the collection is build up. like

```
Collection<String>
```

This answer is all about logic. it may or may not contain the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't understand your question really.. why you can't just use the normal iterator?

I will say to you how to create a basic iterator, to let you understand how things works in basic then adapt your solution:

Suppose we need to iterate over a List<T> and you want to create an helper class to do it.

```
class ListIterator<T>
```

You need two private fields

- The list to iterate
- The pointers to the last item

and 3 methods + 1 constructor

- hasNext() -> Boolean, returns true if there are more items to iterate
- next() -> Return the next element in the list
- reset() -> Reset the interal pointer
- constructor -> Just takes as argument the list to iterate

How will look the fields?

```
private final List<T> list; // The list where this call will iterate
private int pointer; // The pointer to the next iterable item
```

As said in the description,  the constructor will take the reference to the list so it will just be

```
public ListIterator(List<T> list)
{
    this.list = list;
    pointer = 0;
}
```

save the reference and set pointer to 0 (start).

Let's talk about the methods:

`hasNext` should check if our current pointer has reached the size of the list.
So it will just be `(pointer != list.size())`

```
public boolean hasNext()
{
    return (pointer != list.size());
}
```

Will be true if more items are avaitable, false otherwise.

`next` return the next item if any. Could be simplified by using our hasNext method so it will be

```
public T next()
{
    if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException("no field");

    return list.get(pointer++);
}
```

Things to notice:

- T is the return because our list is type T
- list.get(pointer++) we first get the item from the list in position `pointer` then we add 1 to the pointer

The reset method is just a `pointer = 0`.

```
public void reset()
{
    pointer = 0;
}
```

---

**How to use it?**

Like other iterators, create a new object of type ListIterator and pass the list to iterate.

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("Hello");
test.add("World");
test.add("Whatsapp");

ListIterator<String> iterator = new ListIterator<String>(test);
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```